# Is it possible to downgrade Laravel 5.5.40 to 5.5.20?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, compiler-errors

The thing is I'm having too many problems after doing the `composer update`, I'm developing a web system using [adminlte](https://github.com/acacha/adminlte-laravel)  and for some reason I started to get errors that they before didn't exist.

Here is the first example, I can't even loging and if I try to click the checkbox I get more errors 
[image]

Also when I try to send data with a post method it gives me this `'The page has expired due to inactivity'` and yes I do have the `{{ csrf_field() }}` on every post method so the only thing that I think its causing all of this, is a problem with the version and for some reason they are not compatible with some stuff of laravel.

Have anyone dealt with this? what should i do? Should i create a new project and copy and paste everything?

Thx for the help btw

Comment: I'm not confident a different minor version of 5.5 will make a difference for you.

Comment: @Devon Everything was working a week ago, its really frustrating, but I think it for that little version

Answer (score 2):

Before doing anything else clear your cache `php artisan cache:clear` and `composer dump-autoload`. A lot of those post update errors can be fixed with those two commands. If that does not work take a look at your log to see exactly what is causing the error before downgrading. 5.5.20 to 5.5.40 are only patch updates and should not require you to change anything in your code.

If none of that works you can specify a specific laravel version in your composer.json file and then run `composer update`. I would avoid downgrading patches if possible.

Answer (score 1):

In composer.json fix it

```
 "laravel/framework": "5.5.20",
```

see also https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/versions.md